# javascript facebook login redirect uri

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am newbie on facebook api and I make a login with facebook application but when I enter any page api redirect main page . I want to stay page that I was . 
forexample :

I'm in `main/news/nba-orlando` page and I want to login with facebook and I click the button then popup show. If i accept, api redirect `main` bu I want to stay `main/news/nba-orlando` page ...
how can I do that ?

```
FB.init({
    appId        : '{api_id}',
    redirect_uri : document.URL,
    cookie       : true,
    xfbml        : true,
    version      : 'v2.5'
});
```

Comment: What does you set redirect_uri to?

Comment: @WizKid redirect uri is main/news/nba-orlando at that moment. ( www.{site_name}.com/main/news/nba-orlando ... ok ?

Comment: May be you don't need the line
`redirect_uri : document.URL,`

Remove it and it should work normally.

Answer (score 5):

[FB.init](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.6) is only for initializing the JavaScript SDK and there is no `redirect_uri` parameter as you can see in the docs. [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.6) is for login, you can redirect with JavaScript after login:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //user just authorized your app
        window.location.href = 'xxx';
    }
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

More information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: sorry, but i cannot work with that error description. what does that mean? did you debug the code?

Comment: read the whole article i added to my answer. everything you need to know about login with the js sdk is in there, with a full example. redirection can just be done with the code that is in my answer directly.

Comment: i did it but not work . after login page goes to index . i want page stay in whereever i use this login button .

Comment: then...don´t redirect? ;) - just remove the line with window.location.href and it will stay on the page. i thought you want to redirect, as you tried to use a redirect_uri...